# What could be the cause of my ajax call being delayed?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, rest, glassfish

I am working on a notification service for a website. I want to be able to receive notifications in real time, so I am using a Java AsyncResponse to accomplish that. I am running into an issue where the backend of my ajax call doesn't get run until 20 seconds after the call in some cases. To test it, I am starting up 3 pages and then attempting to add a new notification. If I wait long enough, there is no issue, but if I don't wait, not every page gets updated since not every page is polling. Is there something that I am doing wrong that is causing the issue, or is there something I can do to identify what is causing the issue? Thanks!

Java Code:

```
@Path("/demo0825/notifications")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class NotificationsResource {

@Singleton
@Startup
public static class Storage{
    public static ArrayList<AsyncResponse> arList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
}

@GET
@Path("/poll")
public void pollNotifications(@Suspended AsyncResponse ar){
    Date dateobj = new Date();
    synchronized (Storage.lock) {
        Storage.arList.add(ar);
    }
}

@POST
public final Response addNotification(Notification pData) throws Exception {
    try (NotificationDataAccess dataAccess = new NotificationDataAccess()) {
        dataAccess.add(pData);
        synchronized (Storage.lock) {
            for (AsyncResponse ar : Storage.arList) {
                ar.resume(pData);
            }
            Storage.arList.clear();
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Javascript code:

```
pollNotifications = function(){
    console.log("here");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/atrt_ent/rest/demo0825/notifications/poll",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            ...
            }
        },
        complete: function(){
            console.log("here");
            pollNotifications();
        }
    });
}
pollNotifications();
```

I am using chrome and showing the timestamp so that the first `console.log("here")` logs when the ajax gets called, and then I can see when the date in the java code with a debug statement. I have also done this without the lock and have gotten the same result.

Comment: I'm not a java developer or whatever language this is, but, my guess is `synchronized (Storage.lock) {` says "don't let anyone else access this property", meaning, only one request can access it at any given time. So, if you have three tabs open, each tab will have to wait for the request from the previous to complete before it's request can access that property.

Comment: I'll bet that 20 seconds you describe is the suspension timeout in the RESTful service. Try setting a timeout handler and see if it gets called. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html#setTimeoutHandler-javax.ws.rs.container.TimeoutHandler-

Comment: I actually updated it so that I have the date check outside of the lock and it doesn't change anything. That was something that I had thought of as well.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for the suggestion since it is exactly 20 seconds, but when I added `ar.setTimeoutHandler((asyncResp) -> asyncResp.resume(Response.status(Response.Status.REQUEST_TIMEOUT).build()));` the code in the handler does not ever called.

Comment: @Gimby I added a debug break on that code which doesn't get hit and nothing changes with the behavior.

Comment: I just added code to set a 10 second timeout for the AsyncResponse and it now hits the timeout handler every time.

Comment: I have to throw in the towel here, I'd have to recreate a small version for myself to see what's going on. For clarity towards others I'd add the logging output to the question detailing which element (javascript, rest method) created the log line and at what time, to give a sense of what happens when.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Object lock is a `static` object. So, using it in `pollNotifications` affect `addNotification`. You are using the *arList* `ArrayList` only inside `synchronized` blocks.

I recomend you to use `Collections.synchronizedList` instead of ArrayList itself. This should work fine: `public static List<AsyncResponse> arList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<AsyncResponse>());`

Now, you can remove the synchronized blocks and the lock object itself because the JVM control the object synchronization.

Comment: This is cleaner (which is always welcome), but does not solve the issue. If I open three pages which all fire the ajax call at the same time, one call will go through right away, then the other two will wait about 20 seconds before starting. If I then post a notification, I get the same behavior of one ajax request going through right away and the other two taking about 20 seconds to start.